# Issue with URL helper

Tags: laravel-4

I'm having an issue with the URL helper method in Laravel 4. Basically what is happening is that on my local environment it is outputting the links fine:

`"http://127.0.0.1:8080/route" goes to "/route"`

However when I have deployed this to the staging environment I am getting this issue where Laravel is outputting it as:

`"http://example.com/http://example.com/route"`

This is happening with all code for generating urls for example:

`{{link_to_action('ProjectsController@create', 'Create Project')}}`

would create:

`http://example.com/http://example.com/projects/create`

Any ideas? (I am using Apache 2.2, CentOS 6 and PHP 5.5 on the staging environment)

Comment: post your URL code in your view that is causing the error.

Comment: Is the link_to_action wrapped inside of anything? i.e. <a>{{link_to_action}}</a>?

Comment: Just an `<li>`. As a further note it actually works if I do: `{{link_to('projects', 'Manage Projects')}}` instead